# TCP/IP Connection with Python, .recv() gives nothing back

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have a little problem. I try to comunicate between a Rasperry Pi 4 and a 2d-laserscanner. The scanner works fine and i have a program with an terminal from the producer. With the terminal sending and recieving works fine. The sensor has 3 ports to comunicate. 2111 for binary input and output. 2112 for ASCII Input and output. And 2113 for ASCII input and output as an UDP port.

I tried a simple code to test if I get anything back. But I always have a timeout when I try to recieve the data.

Maybe it's very simple too solve but im stuck since two days and can't find a solution.

```
start = "sEA LMDscandata 1"
start = TStart.encode()
print(TStart)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.5', 2112))
s.send(TStart)


data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
print ("received data:", data)
```

Comment: You are sending over `TStart`, do you mean to `s.send(start)` instead?

Comment: You haven't sent a valid command to the scanner, so no response is expected.  Every reference to the command string `sEA LMDscandata 1` I find online shows that text to be enclosed by the control characters `<STX>` and `<ETX>`, which would be written as `\x02` and `\x03` in a Python string literal.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks. That was the problem...